# Can I reuse underlayment for vinyl flooring replacement?

Tags: vinyl-flooring

I have Armstrong vinyl sheeting over underlayment. If I remove the vinyl can I use the sub floor that's already there?

Comment: I want to save a few dollars and remove the vinyl sheeting, but want to keep the subfloor that's already there instead of adding another layer of luen.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. The answer is: it depends. If you give us more information (what layers are on the floor right now?) we're more likely to give you a helpful answer.

Comment: The wood under your vinyl can be used as long as it meets the requirements for your new floor.  Unless your subfloor is rather thin and you are moving to a wide plank hardwood or tiling 98% of the time the old subfloor is fine.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you meant was underlayment; but generally, yes you can still use it, unless you suspect or find damage. And scraping up vinyl is so tedious that many people or contractors would not even bother to tear up the old vinyl before laying down another floor, but I suppose that depends on the situation... for example maybe new vinyl over the old vinyl is not a good idea because the old vinyl is not in good condition anymore.